# Extract hashtag from a string till the occurrence of a special character

Tags: javascript, regex, hashtag

I have hashtags in my string. And I can extract the test starting from the # character. But I want to break the extraction at the point where a special character comes.

Example:

String: This is a #first./23k%^ hashtag 
Required extract: #first

String: This is another test #hashtag/';123one 
Required extract: #hashtag

I did good amount of search on how to do this in JavaScript but I wasn't successful. Kindly help.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "special character"? Is it some specific termination character? Or just a character not part of a "normal characters set"?

Comment: Just a non-alphanumeric character.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use this match:

```
str="This is a #first./23k%^ hashtag #foo.#$$ 45";
var m = str.match(/#\w+/g);

//=> ["#first", "#foo"]
```

Comment: What if I have multiple hashtags and it gives me two matches for every hashtag, one with a hash and one without hash. It would become a little complex extracting them out. Isnt there a direct approach ?

Comment: for that you can use `g`  switch (see updated) and I removed capturing part so all the matches can be found but you better provide examples of that case as well.

Comment: `\w` matches `_` in addition to alphanumeric values, not sure if that is relevant for the original poster.